# Kendo UI Model - Extend "define" with new properties?

Tags: kendo-ui

Using Kendo's MVVM framework, I have a situation where I want to extend the underlying object that is made with `kendo.data.Model.define` to include new properties, like this ...

So I would want to define a new property, for the sake of example, just called `newProperty`, and it would be `true` by default unless otherwise specified.

```js
var Model = kendo.data.Model.define({
    Id: "Id",
    fields: {
        Id: {
            type: "string"
        },
        Name: {
            type: "string"
        },
        Quality: {
            newProperty: false,
            defaultValue: {
                Id: "qualities/none",
                Name: "None",
                CSS: "none",
                Order: 0
            }
        }
    });
```

so I would create the view Model like this...

```js
var viewModel = new Model({
   Id: null,
   Name: null,
   Quality: {}
});

console.log(viewModel.Name.newProperty); // expected to be true (default)
console.log(viewModel.Quality.newProperty); // expected to be false
```

It does not stop me from doing this, but then the property value is not passed on to the new view model that is created from this model. Is there a way to do this?

## Update

The reason I want to do this is because I want to re-use as much code as possible, and to keep the actual code for the individual pages as slim and clear as possible. I intend to define my "models" somewhere else, and they will have a lot of the underlying logic needed to behave. Then in the pages where I need to use them, just call them up as instances (Like on the kendo examples) and have them very simple and flat. I feel that defining the 'schema' of the model is far, far more reliable than trying to get it right on each implementation.

Comment: How do you create the view model? Can you add some code to illustrate how you expected it to work?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with the default implementation, so I think you'd have to build it yourself. Depending on the exact requirements, it could get complicated. Your example is also a bit confusing, since you're trying to access `newProperty` on a field of type string - only objects can have such a property. I suppose you could store such a property for strings, numbers etc. in a separate structure.

As long as having the property on objects is enough, and you don't need to pass values when you new up your model, something like this might work:

```js
// keep a reference to the original init method
kendo.data.ObservableObject.fn._myInit = kendo.data.ObservableObject.fn.init;
// override it
kendo.data.ObservableObject.fn.init = function (value) {
    var member,
        field;

    kendo.data.ObservableObject.fn._myInit.call(this, value);

    for (field in value) {
        // add default properties ...
        if (!this[field].hasOwnProperty("newProperty")) {
            this[field].newProperty = true;
        }
        if (!this[field].hasOwnProperty("otherProperty")) {
            this[field].otherProperty = "something or other";
        }
    }
}

var Model = kendo.data.Model.define({
    Id: "Id",
    fields: {
        Id: {
            type: "string"
        },
        Name: {
            defaultValue: {
                Value: "John Doe"
            }
        },
        Quality: {
            defaultValue: {
                Id: "qualities/none",
                Name: "None",
                CSS: "none",
                Order: 0, 
                newProperty: false
            }
        }
    }
});

var modelInstance = new Model();

modelInstance.set("Id", "abcde");

console.log(modelInstance.get("Quality.newProperty")); // false: as set in Model.define
console.log(modelInstance.get("Name.newProperty")); // default: true
console.log(modelInstance.get("Id.newProperty")); // fails because string type, not object
```

This will add the default property where it wasn't specified through Model.define.

For more complex behavior, you may have to write your own Model.define method and/or rewrite ObservableObject.

Comment: Actually this is perfect. This is exactly what I needed. The purpose is to reduce clutter in the implementation, and leave the more detailed aspects up to the model declaration elsewhere, and this does that perfectly. Thank you very much!